# Proxmox 6.2-4 GPU Passthrough to Windows 10 Guest: Code 43

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, gpu, proxmox

### Host

`Proxmox 6.2-4` on a HP Compaq 8200 Elite Convertible Minitower w/ i7-2600 and 16GB RAM.

Integrated graphics is enabled, though there doesn't seem to be an option to choose between the iGPU and dGPU when booting in the BIOS, so it always uses the latter until Proxmox is loaded. Requisite virtualization options are enabled (VT-d, etc.).

### Configuration

I followed [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/b5xpua/the_ultimate_beginners_guide_to_gpu_passthrough/) guide for configuring Proxmox and the VM, but here are the important bits:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt pcie_acs_override=downstream,multifunction nofb nomodeset video=vesafb:off video=efifb:off"`

`~# ls /etc/modprobe.d/`:
`blacklist.conf  iommu_unsafe_interrupts.conf  kvm.conf  pve-blacklist.conf  vfio.conf` (with the same content as specified in the guide)

[`~# lspci -nnk`](https://pastebin.com/BEVcMkXz)

[`~# cat /etc/pve/qemu-server/100.conf`](https://pastebin.com/JRM94xBv)

### Guest

`Windows 10 1909 (18363.592) (Unactivated)`

Task Manager correctly reports i7-2600 as the CPU, but can detect that it is in a VM (`Virtual machine: Yes`)

I used `352.84-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe` as the driver, directly downloaded from Nvidia's website.

GPU reports `Code 43` in Device Manager, and there is no output on the attached monitor.

Please do not hesitate to ask for any more needed information. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the vm conf.

```
args: -cpu 'host,-hypervisor,+kvm_pv_unhalt,+kvm_pv_eoi,hv_spinlocks=0x1fff,hv_vapic,hv_time,hv_reset,hv_vpindex,hv_runtime,hv_relaxed,kvm=off,hv_vendor_id=intel'
```

Comment: Also, if you follow that guide, make sure you remove the Display. So in the VM hardware tab, set Display to "None". Since in the guide, we set all the other hardware as Virtio, but the Display. So Nvidia can still detect that the display is virtualized. I have a Windows 10 VM run with Nvidia drivers installed, and when I go to the control panel under CPU, windows knows it's a VM.